# EnterKey to press button in VBA Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform in Excel that asks for a username and password. Once you enter your password if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it just "selects" the next item which is the `LogIn` button, but it doesn't press it. You have to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to actually press the button.

How can I make it so when the user presses enter on his keyboard the LogIn button is pressed and the code associated to is runs (`Logincode_click`)?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792836/press-enter-in-textbox-and-execute-button-function-in-vba (and the other one has a much better answer than any of these)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Press enter in textbox and execute button function in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792836/press-enter-in-textbox-and-execute-button-function-in-vba)

Answer (score 21):

You could also use the TextBox's On Key Press event handler:

```
'Keycode for "Enter" is 13
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
         Logincode_Click
    End If
End Sub
```

Textbox1 is an example. Make sure you choose the textbox you want to refer to and also Logincode_Click is an example sub which you call (run) with this code. Make sure you refer to your preferred sub

Comment: +1. This may be better or more precise than my answer, which would also fire the event on the `Tab` key, or a mouse-click out of the textbox.

Comment: @DavidZemens, I get `Compile error:` `Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name` but I'm sure I don't have another `EnterTextBox` named procedure. 
`TextBox1=EnterTextBox` and `Logincode_Click = CommandButton1_Click`in my example. What would I'm missing?

Comment: @Mertinc I would suggest asking your own question :) it will before much easier to assist you if you ask a good question and include the code you're trying to use.  it's v unlikely that anyone will respond to a comment on a 3 year old answer to someone else's question!

Comment: haahah @DavidZemens I definitely know your point of view but I'm sure if I'll ask my own question people will mark it as duplicate, because it's really duplicate, even I might vote for duplication :) Jacob D seems like not visiting this site and as you were active in this question *once upon a time* I tagged you, but anyway sorry for inconvenience and thanks for your response. (ps: it's actually 4 years old! :) )

Comment: @Mertinc people will be less-inclined to mark it as a duplicate if you link to this question (and/or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792836/press-enter-in-textbox-and-execute-button-function-in-vba) **and** show the code you're using, explaining the specific problem and that you've *tried* to implement the other solutions (unsuccessfully). I'm sure you will have an answer that way :0

Comment: +1, side note: KeyPress works in Access, but not in Excel https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/77430-key-press-event-not-working-enter.html

Comment: Rather than the cryptic `KeyCode = 13` use `KeyCode = KeyCodeConstants.vbKeyReturn`.  This makes it clear in the code which button triggers that code.  Plus, when searching for a button, you can type `KeyCodeConstants.` and intellisense shows a list of all available buttons.  @drognisep posted a similar answer.

Comment: In Excel, this code goes in the same worksheet module as the ActiveX button.

Comment: @Mertinc I was also getting the `Compile error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name` error.  Instead of using the arguments `KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer` I instead used `ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer` which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 21):

Be sure to avoid "magic numbers" whenever possible, either by defining your own constants, or by using the built-in *vbXXX* constants.

In this instance we could use *vbKeyReturn* to indicate the enter key's keycode (replacing *YourInputControl* and *SubToBeCalled*).

```
   Private Sub YourInputControl_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
        If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
             SubToBeCalled
        End If
   End Sub
```

This prevents a whole category of compatibility issues and simple typos, especially because VBA capitalizes identifiers for us.

Cheers!

Comment: +1 for using built in constants instead of cryptic numbers.  Plus, if your looking for a specific button's keycode you can type `KeyCodeConstants.` and intellisense shows a drop-down list of keycodes for all buttons.

Comment: I got an error without using the `ByVal` lines which the VBA Editor populated for me. As well, I love the rec to use vbXXX constants. `vbKeyEscape` Here is the list for anyone else! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/keycode-constants

Comment: Also worth noting, I was able to use `KeyUp` for `vbKeyEscape`, but not for `vbKeyReturn`. While both worked w/ `KeyDown`. There for I'll only use `KeyDown` moving forward.

Answer (score 5):

This one worked for me

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
        If KeyCode = 13 Then
             Button1_Click
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Further to @Penn's comment, and in case the link breaks, you can also achieve this by setting the `Default` property of the button to `True` (you can set this in the properties window, open by hitting <kbd>F4</kbd>)

That way whenever <kbd>Return</kbd> is hit, VBA knows to activate the button's click event. Similarly setting the `Cancel` property of a button to `True` would cause that button's click event to run whenever <kbd>ESC</kbd> key is hit (useful for gracefully exiting the Userform)

---

Source: Olivier Jacot-Descombes's answer accessible here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22793040/6609896

Answer (score 1):

Use the TextBox's `Exit` event handler:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Logincode_Click  
End Sub
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to be working. where am i supposed to put this code. In the module of the userform?

Comment: Yes, this goes in the UserForm's module and make sure that the sub name `TextBox1_Exit` corresponds to your text box's name.  So, if your textbox is called `MyTextBox` then it should be `Private Sub MyTextBox_Exit(...`

Comment: But I think Jacob's answer below is more precise than mine. Same caveats to naming and placement of the subroutine in the UserForm's module.

Comment: I get a compile error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name. it highlights the forst line :"Private Sub pwBox_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)" pwBox is the name of the textbox where they enter the password. thats where the average person just presses enter after having written their password and thus the code should run. Any idea why this doesn't compile?

Comment: If you're using @Jacob D's answer, I suggest you ask him :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can simply use:

`SendKeys "{ENTER}"` at the end of code linked to the Username field.

And so you can skip pressing ENTER Key once (one time).
And as a result, the next button ("Log In" button here) will be activated. And when you press ENTER once (your desired outcome), It will run code which is linked with "Log In" button.