# Press enter in textbox and execute button function in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a login form to my database done in Access 2010 and using VBA code. I want to be able to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on `txtboxPassword` and automatically execute `btnLogin_Click` event. I tried this:

```
Private Sub txtboxPassword_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
 If KeyCode = 13 Then
    btnLogin_Click
 End If
End Sub
```

What I get is a self-made error saying Password is incorrect. If I debug I see that actually `txtPassword` is `null`, but I just typed the text in it!

However If I click the Login button with the mouse it works perfect. Why does vba behave like that? How can I do it to make it work?

**NOTE** I also tried with:

- KeyPress: after I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the focus goes to `btnLogin` (maybe also because the tab order is like that), but the `btnLogin_Click` event is not executed.
- KeyUp: same like KeyPress.

Comment: What do you mean by `txtPassword` is null? Textboxes have a `Text` property. But that one is usually an empty string but not `null`.

Comment: When in debug mode I hover the mouse over txtboxPassword.Value I get `null`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The buttons in Access have a property  called `Default` (on the *Other* property page). If you set it to `Yes`
the form calls the button click event handler automatically, when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. No need for additional Key-event handling.

There is also a `Cancel` property. If you set it to `Yes` for a button, the form activates it automatically when the user types the <kbd>Esc</kbd>-key. Very practical for *Cancel* buttons.

Comment: I couldn't find that property either in the btnLogin or the form. Can you guide me a little bit more. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, my answer was for VB.NET. I changed my answer for Access now. In Access you can set the `Default` property of the "OK" button.

Comment: As referenced in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125240/enterkey-to-press-button-in-vba-userform#answer-42952176) this also works in Excel

Answer (score 2):

to activate KeyCode, you need to set **Key Preview** Property on form to **YES** (it will be at the bottom)

```
If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
    Your_fuction_here
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant reproduce exactly your problem, but some time ago I had somewhat similar issue and solved it by adding:

```
Private Sub txtboxPassword_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
  If KeyCode = 13 Then
     btnLogin_Click
     KeyCode.Value = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Didn't work. I got "Compiled error: Invalid qualifier" and `KeyCode` on `KeyCode.Value` is marked in blue.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to like `KeyCode.Value = 0`.    I presume the purpose of adding this is so the normal keypress action is absorbed?

Answer (score 0):

On the button you wish to action go to properties 'Other' and set the 'Default' to Yes. Then when you click on enter when in the text box it will action the button.

Answer (score 0):

[KeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-keypress-event-access) rather than KeyDown works for me, and calling the _Click sub avoids sending triggers that may fire other events.

```
Private Sub txtboxPassword_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 13 Then
         Call btnLogin_Click
    End If
End Sub
```