# Press enter to search values text box

Tags: ms-access

I know this question has been answered before but I'm having trouble following  instructions.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792836/press-enter-in-textbox-and-execute-button-function-in-vba) answer seems spot on but I can't figure out how to set the default button in any settings at all. I Simply do not see this option in the properties menu or in the "view code" area.

I haven't been able to find a good example of how to implement this in any code either, appreciate any help.

I tried to add the following code to the Enter event of the Search text box:

```
Me.Toggle47.DefaultValue = True
```

Now when I press enter the button is depressed, but the filters are not applied.

Could this have anything to do with the fact that I made the button in the Macro Builder? If I go in Design View and highlight the Search button I can see in the Property Sheet that the On Click command is an Embedded Macro, specifically,

```
ApplyFilter Where Condition = [Name] Like "*" & [Forms]![2-Add/Edit Chemical]![txtNameSearch] & "*"
```

Is it an issue that I did this using the Macro Builder rather than in the "view code" area? I'm not sure why it would, but then again I'm new to MSA. Thanks.

[image: Screen of [property sheets]

[image: Form, subform]

Comment: can you get us a screen shot of the "other" tab on your properties windows?

Comment: The answer you refer to is for a command button, which has a `.Default` property, which is different to a toggle button's `.DefaultValue` property that you are trying to use. I don't think a toggle button has a `.Default` property for you to use like this.

Comment: If switching to a command button would solve this I would definitely give that a shot. I had looked into toggle vs command and didn't see much difference. This difference seems significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the form's `KeyPress` event to listen-out for the enter key being pressed (Enter key is KeyAscii number 13).

```vb
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)

    If _
        KeyAscii = 13 _
    Then

        Me.Filter = "Name Like '*" & Me.txtNameSearch & "*'"
        Me.FilterOn = True

    Else

        ' code you want to run when something other than Enter key is pressed
        ' (probably leave this blank)

    End If

End Sub
```

I think you'll also need to set the form's `Key Preview` event to Yes to get this to work (right at the bottom of the form's event list)

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, unfortunately I've been relying on the Macro Builder. Could you point me in the right direction to get similar results as clicking "Macro Builder" >> Apply Filter >> Where Condition: `[Name] Like "*" & [Forms]![2-Add/Edit Chemical]![txtNameSearch] & "*"`. I'm just not too sure on when to but after the `Then` function.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your form? What is it that will be getting the filter applied to is it a form or subform or something else?

Comment: Just posted a screen above. The form view is "Split Form". The filter is being applied to a query which lists all items.

Comment: @user3564760 I would say Matt Hall's answer is going to be what you need.   I have looked for anyway to access Keyascii in a macro and it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I've entered your code and changed the Key Preview to "Yes" and it works well!

Comment: Wasn't sure if I should post a new question, I'll ask anyways. Any idea how to add a conditional to the `KeyAscii = 13 _` line to also detect if txtNameSearch has focus? Something like `&& Me.txtNameSearch.HasFocus` (This didn't work). Problem I'm having is that if someone presses enter when entering data, it sort of remove all the work and performs a search instead. (Way around that would be to use tab... but would be better to add a conditional I think)

Comment: Perhaps move the code to the `KeyPress` event of the textbox instead of the form? I've not tried, but that seems like it could work :)

Comment: Thanks Matt! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this answer because I've found multiple solutions that all work a little bit differently.

- Matt Halls answer works perfectly and is what I'm currently using.
- Another solution that worked was to convert my Search toggle button into a Search command button. Apparently command buttons have the added property value of `Default`, which if set to `Yes`, will be triggered if the Enter key is pressed. This solution seems to behave just as Matt's solution.
- An earlier solution which worked fairly well was to copy the trigger even from the Search button, and place it in the `On Lost Focus` event. This worked quite well with the added (possible) benefit of, after pressing Enter, highlighting the text box text again completely.

I've seen this question pop up a lot, hopefully it's this simple for everyone else.