# MS Access VBA call sub works on the first pass but not on the second

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have hit a wall and I am completely at a loss.

So I have a Form in MS Access. In it I have a single text box and a single button. When I type in a number in the text box and then click the button it opens a public sub which then runs a few queries, updates the database, displays a text box and then clears out the text box. This all works perfectly.

My issue is trying to do the exact same thing with hitting enter in the text box. The strangest thing is that the code works fine right after I open up the form, but all subsequent attempts give the following error until I close the form and reopen it:

```
Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out why it does what I want the first time, then falls apart on me.

Here is the complete VBA code for reference:

```
    Option Compare Database
Public Sub Cut_Update()

    On Error GoTo Cut_Update_Err

        DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE_WIP_Cut", acViewNormal, acEdit
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE_LastRun", acViewNormal, acEdit

        MsgBox "Database Updated"
        [Forms]![Portal_02_Cut]![WO_Num].Value = ""
Cut_Update_Exit:
        Exit Sub

Cut_Update_Err:
        MsgBox Error$
        Resume Cut_Update_Exit

End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Return in Textbox
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub WO_Num_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        Call Cut_Update
        Me.Refresh
    End If
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Command2_Click
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Call Cut_Update
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you debug with a break point and run each statement step by step? That will narrow down the issue to a particular line of code.

Comment: Have you tried without `Me.Refresh`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Press enter in textbox and execute button function in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792836/press-enter-in-textbox-and-execute-button-function-in-vba)

Comment: That is the most simple and elegant solution, @Rene

Comment: Rene, that was exactly what I had been looking for and I for the life of me could not figure that setting out. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you do in between the calls in the form is:

```
[Forms]![Portal_02_Cut]![WO_Num].Value = ""
```

So, try with either:

```
[Forms]![Portal_02_Cut]![WO_Num].Text = ""
```

or:

```
[Forms]![Portal_02_Cut]![WO_Num].Value = Null
```

Answer (score 0):

My only guess is that the update is trying to update with a non numeric value.
Let me know

```
       Option Compare Database 
       Public Sub Cut_Update()

                On Error GoTo Cut_Update_Err

                '' Make sure it is numeric
                If IsNumeric([WO_Num].Value) Then

                    DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE_WIP_Cut", acViewNormal, acEdit
                    DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE_LastRun", acViewNormal, acEdit

                    MsgBox "Database Updated"
                    [Forms]![Portal_02_Cut]![WO_Num].Value = ""

                End If

            Cut_Update_Exit:
                    Exit Sub

            Cut_Update_Err:
                    MsgBox Error$
                    Resume Cut_Update_Exit

     End Sub 
'------------------------------------------------------------ ' Return in Textbox ' 
'------------------------------------------------------------ 
Private Sub WO_Num_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
                If KeyCode = 13 Then
                    Call Cut_Update
                    Me.Refresh
                End If 
End Sub 
'------------------------------------------------------------ ' Command2_Click ' 
'------------------------------------------------------------ 
        Private Sub Command2_Click()
                Call Cut_Update 
        End Sub
```

Comment: Ok well that got me closer. So when I added your little check I am able to get it to run the first time as before. After it clears out when I type in the number and then  hit enter it just highlights the text. If I hit enter again it successfully runs the code. Not sure why it has to have me hit return twice.... It is late, but I might see if I can brute force through with a loop tomorrow.

Comment: Compare`[Forms]![Portal_02_Cut]![WO_Num].Value`with`[Forms]![Portal_02_Cut]![WO_Num].Text`. Value property may not be set in KeyUp-Event, but if you use the button the control loses focus annd then. Value is set to.Text.