# Textbox on Access form passing previous value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created a search form.
[image: Search form]

There is a text box for the search text. The user triggers the search event by either clicking on the search button or pressing the enter key.

The button click event is working.

On pressing of enter key for the first time the text box is passing the value which was entered in the text box from the previous event. If I press the enter key a second time the current value is passed.

For instance on the form load the text box is empty then I enter the search text as "Ali" and press enter key then the value "NULL" is passed and once again I press enter key then the value "Ali" is passed.

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
    Dim SQL, strSearch As String
    strSearch = Nz(Me.txtSearch.Value, "")
    SQL = "SELECT tbl_mst_Employee_Details.emp_ID, " _
        & "tbl_mst_Employee_Details.emp_Name " _
        & "FROM tbl_mst_Employee_Details " _
        & "where [emp_Name] like '*" & strSearch & "*' " _
        & "ORDER BY tbl_mst_Employee_Details.emp_Name;"
    Me.lstEmployee.RowSource = SQL
    Me.lstEmployee.Requery
    Me.txtEmpID.Value = ""
    Me.txtEmpName.Value = ""
    Me.Refresh
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.txtEmpID.Value = ""
    Me.txtEmpName.Value = ""
    Me.txtSearch.Value = ""
End Sub

Private Sub lstEmployee_Click()
    With lstEmployee
        Me.txtEmpID.Value = .Column(0)
        Me.txtEmpName.Value = .Column(1)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub lstEmployee_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Forms!frmEmployeeShiftDetails.txtEmpID.Value = Me.txtEmpID
    Forms!frmEmployeeShiftDetails.txtEmpName.Value = Me.txtEmpName
    DoCmd.Close
    Forms!frmEmployeeShiftDetails.txtEmpID.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub lstEmployee_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        lstEmployee_DblClick (0)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtSearch_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        btnSearch_Click
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792836/press-enter-in-textbox-and-execute-button-function-in-vba

Comment: The reason why your code doesn't work: the new `.Value` isn't set until you leave the textbox. Compare this recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59556810/ms-access-vba-call-sub-works-on-the-first-pass-but-not-on-the-second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set the focus to the search button first.

Additionally I would also check for pressing tab (and use constants for both, return and tab).

For having constant UI behaviour I would take care that the search button receives the focus when pressing tab in the search box, so set the correct tab order in the form.

```
Private Sub txtSearch_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Or KeyCode = vbKeyTab Then
        btnSearch.SetFocus
        btnSearch_Click
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andre, this has actually solved the problem

Comment: @Anees: You're welcome. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find that it solved your problem.

Comment: @Andre
Hi Andre,
I am facing one problem. I don't know how can I send a direct request on this portal so I am using the method to reply as comment.
The following Link will take you to that post
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752046/error-3421-data-type-connection-error-multy-column-combobox)