# Error 3421 Data Type Connection Error Multy Column Combobox

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, recordset

I have a scenario where in I have to save "STATUS" code into table from a "COMBO BOX". This Combo Box shows "Status ID" and "Status Description" together. But while saving I need to save only "Status ID"

Following is the code for the complete form functionality. Error is occurring on click of "SAVE" button. On line where I am assigning the value from combo to "Recordset Column" on line # 77 or 90.

```
'    rs![status_ID] = Me.cboStatus.Column(1)



Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim db As Database
Dim rs, rs2, rs3 As Recordset
Dim SQL, SQL1, SQL2 As String
Dim intChk As Integer
Private Sub btnFirst_Click()
    If Not rs.BOF Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Set_Data
    End If
    If rs.EOF Then
        rs.MovePrevious
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btnLast_Click()
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        rs.MoveLast
        Set_Data
    End If
    If rs.EOF Then
        rs.MovePrevious
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btnNew_Click()
    SQL2 = "select Max(job_ID) as JID from tbl_mst_JobOrder"
    Set rs3 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL2, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    If Not rs3.EOF And Not rs3.BOF Then
        Me.txtJobID = rs3!JID + 1
    End If
    Set rs3 = Nothing
    TxtSetEmpty
End Sub
Private Sub btnNext_Click()
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        rs.MoveNext
        Set_Data
    End If
    If rs.EOF Then
        rs.MovePrevious
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btnPrevious_Click()
    If Not rs.BOF Then
        rs.MovePrevious
        Set_Data
    End If
    If rs.BOF Then
        rs.MoveNext
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
Dim SQL As String
IfEmpty
Dim sqlShift As String
If intChk = 1 Then
    intChk = 0
    Exit Sub
Else
    SQL = "select job_ID from qryJobDetails " _
    & "where job_ID = " & Me.txtJobID
    Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
    If Not rs2.EOF Then
        Dim CHK As String
        Me.lblChk.Caption = rs2![job_ID]
    End If
    Set rs2 = Nothing
    If Me.txtJobID.Value = Me.lblChk.Caption Then
    Dim msgUpd, msgNew, strCobSt As String
    strCobSt = Me.cboStatus.Column(1)
    msgUpd = "Do you want to update Location ID " & Me.lblChk.Caption
        If MsgBox(msgUpd, vbYesNo, "Location Update") = vbYes Then
            rs.Edit
            rs![job_Date] = Me.dtpJDate.Value
            rs![job_Desc] = Me.txtJobDesc
            rs![loc_ID] = Me.txtLocID
            rs![status_ID] = Me.cboStatus.Column(1)
            rs![Comments] = Me.txtComment
            rs.Update
            RefreshListBox
        End If
    Else
        msgNew = "Do you want to add New Location"
        If MsgBox(msgNew, vbYesNo, "Add New Location") = vbYes Then
            rs.AddNew
            rs![job_ID] = Me.txtJobID
            rs![job_Date] = Me.dtpJDate.Value
            rs![job_Desc] = Me.txtJobDesc
            rs![loc_ID] = Me.txtLocID
            rs![status_ID] = Me.cboStatus.Column(1)
            rs![Comments] = Me.txtComment
            rs.Update
            RefreshListBox
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set db = CurrentDb
    SQL = "Select status_ID, status_Desc from tbl_mst_Status order by status_ID"
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)
    Do Until rs2.EOF
        Me.cboStatus.AddItem rs2![status_ID] & "|" & rs2![status_Desc]
        rs2.MoveNext
    Loop
    Set rs2 = Nothing
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryJobDetails", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    RefreshListBox
    Set_Data
End Sub
Private Sub Set_Data()
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        Me.txtJobID = rs![job_ID]
        Me.dtpJDate = rs![job_Date]
        Me.txtJobDesc = rs![job_Desc]
        Me.txtLocID = rs![loc_ID]
        Me.txtLocDec = rs![location_desc]
        Me.cboStatus = rs![status_ID] & "|" & rs![status_Desc]
        Me.txtComment = rs![Comments]
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub RefreshListBox()
    Me.lstJobOrd.RowSource = ""
    Me.lstJobOrd.AddItem "Job Order" & ";" & "Job Date" & ";" & "Job Description" & ";" _
                        & "Loc Description" & ";" & "Loc ID" & ";" & "Sta ID" & ";" _
                        & "Sta Desc" & ";" & "Comments"
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
        Me.lstJobOrd.AddItem rs![job_ID] & ";" & rs![job_Date] & ";" & rs![job_Desc] & ";" _
                        & rs![location_desc] & ";" & rs![loc_ID] & ";" & rs![status_ID] & ";" _
                        & rs![status_Desc] & ";" & rs![Comments]
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.MoveFirst
End Sub
Private Sub TxtSetEmpty()
    Me.txtJobDesc = ""
    Me.dtpJDate = Now()
    Me.txtLocDec = ""
    Me.cboStatus = ""
    Me.txtComment = ""
    Me.txtLocID = ""
End Sub
Private Sub lstJobOrd_Click()
    With Me.lstJobOrd
        Me.txtJobID.Value = .Column(0)
        Me.dtpJDate.Value = .Column(1)
        Me.txtJobDesc.Value = .Column(2)
        Me.txtLocDec.Value = .Column(3)
        Me.txtLocID.Value = .Column(4)
        Me.cboStatus.Value = .Column(5)
        Me.txtComment.Value = .Column(7)
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub IfEmpty()
Dim txtCtr As Control
Dim cboCtr As Control
Dim Str As String
Str = Empty
For Each txtCtr In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf txtCtr Is TextBox Then
        If IsNullOrEmpty(txtCtr) Then
            txtCtr.BackColor = RGB(119, 192, 212)
            txtCtr.BorderColor = RGB(157, 187, 97)
            Str = Str & txtCtr.Tag & vbNewLine
        Else
            txtCtr.BackColor = vbWhite
            txtCtr.BorderColor = RGB(192, 192, 192)
        End If
    End If
Next txtCtr
For Each cboCtr In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf cboCtr Is ComboBox Then
        If IsNullOrEmptyCbo(cboCtr) Then
            cboCtr.BackColor = RGB(119, 192, 212)
            cboCtr.BorderColor = RGB(157, 187, 97)
            Str = Str & cboCtr.Tag & vbNewLine
        Else
            cboCtr.BackColor = vbWhite
            cboCtr.BorderColor = RGB(192, 192, 192)
        End If
    End If
Next cboCtr
If IsNull(Str) Or Str = "" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "Please enter data in the highlited fields. " & vbNewLine & _
    String(52, "_") & vbCrLf & Str, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Data not Complete"
    intChk = 1
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
Private Sub txtLocDec_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 113 Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmLocSer", acNormal, , , acFormAdd, acWindowNormal
    End If
End Sub`
```

Comment: @Andre
Hi Andre,
Can you help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Anees, when you are referring to the columns of your combobox, the first item is held in column(0), not column(1).  I suspect you are asking it to save your Status, not the StatusID.  To check, add the line 
debug.print me.cboStatus.Column(0) & " " & me.cboStatusColumn(1) and you can see in the immediate window which value is in each column.

Comment: Hi @JennyW
Thanks a lot for your valuable guidance. Yes I was making a mistake by giving the column number as 1 it has to be 0.
As my requirement was to save only the "Status ID" and I was showing "Status ID and "Status Description" together so I had to use two small function Left() and InStr() to cut the "Status ID" in separate and to assign that value to the RecordSet to Edit or AddNew.
Following is the Code I have written and solved the error
rs![status_ID] = Left(Me.cboStatus.Column(0), InStr(1, Me.cboStatus.Column(0), "|") - 1)
This also can be assign to any declared variable & used.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted @Anees