# push enter key in text boxt then go to specific cell

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

How to move cursor in text box with enter in text box?

Here is my code, it gives me a syntax error.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Sheets("30").Range("D18") = TextBox2.Value
    TextBox2.Enter Then Sheets("30").Range("E19").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EnterKey to press button in VBA Userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125240/enterkey-to-press-button-in-vba-userform) Alternatively, this solution might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244626/activate-userform-with-only-one-enter/33246450#33246450 Also note, that there is always one button on each form that is the `default` when the `Enter` key is pressed. Just look in the properties of the command button (on your form) you want to be the defaut and set `Default` to `True`. Then the macro behind that button will run whenever someone hits `enter`.

Comment: i don't use userform, just in excel with vba sir.. @ralph

Comment: In this case you are probably looking for a solution like this: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?43146-Solved-leave-the-ActiveX-text-box-pressing-Enter ?

Comment: it's absolutely amazing, sir. thank you @ralph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the Change event, use the KeyUp event and check for the KeyCode vbKeyReturn:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = KeyCodeConstants.vbKeyReturn Then
        Sheets("30").Range("E19").Select
    End If
End Sub
```